# How obtain 24h of diference between two TIMESTAMPS using Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have two variables, and I would like to count the hours between this variable 2020-01-16 15:20:24 and this other variable 2020-01-15 11:01:54

I'm doing a count and I would like to add +1 if the difference is more than 24 hours

I tried with this code:

```
$time = DB::table('incidencia_tiempo')
            ->whereColumn('timeA', '>=', '24:00:00', and, 'timeA', '-', 'TimeB = 24:00:00'))
            ->count();
```

I have a problem because I want to work with days too, for example if have passed two days shouldn't add +1 to the count.. but I don't now how work with days.

Answer (score 2):

try with carbon

```
$dateStart = Carbon::parse($dateStart);
$dateEnd   = Carbon::parse($dateEnd);
$diff      = $dateStart->diffInHours($dateEnd,false);
```

Comment: I've never worked with carbon.. I always have worked with Query Builder

Comment: @LaravelOscar So? Carbon is the right thing to use for dates, and Laravel uses it internally all over.

Comment: how could I transform my query into a carbon function?

Comment: I don't really understand what the query has to do with your question. You said "I would like to count the hours between this variable 2020-01-16 15:20:24 and this other variable 2020-01-15 11:01:54". That can be done with Carbon, no query is required.

Comment: I have two list of dates and I want to count how many dates are higher than 24 hours between the two times